# Using @autowired to store a list of beans dynamically created in another class

Tags: java, spring

I have a class called Drives which dynamically instantiates FsAccess beans.
I have a service class called ServersAccessService which finds FsAccess beans and stores them in a map using @autowired. Is there a way to have the service class initiate the @autowired after Drives is finished instantiating the FsAccess beans?

Service Class:

```
public class ServersAccessService implements DisposableBean {

protected static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ServersAccessService.class);

protected static Map<String, FsAccess> servers = new HashMap<String, FsAccess>();
I
protected Map<String, FsAccess> restrictedServers = new HashMap<String, FsAccess>();

protected boolean isInitialized = false;

protected static Map<String, DrivesCategory> drivesCategories = new HashMap<String, DrivesCategory>();
@Autowired
public void setServers(List<FsAccess> servers) {
    for(FsAccess server: servers) {
        this.servers.put(server.getDriveName(), server);
    }
}
```

Drives class:

```
MyBeanFactory mbf = new MyBeanFactory();

        //loop through each drive in driveList
        for(String name:driveList)
        {

            String fullUri = "smb://naz-fs3/home/"+name;
            String icon = "/esup-portlet-stockage/img/drives/root.png";


            VfsAccessImpl drive = mbf.createInstance();

            //Set attribute information 
            drive.setDriveName(name);
            drive.setIcon(icon);
            drive.setUri(fullUri);
            drive.setContextToken(name);




        }
```

Comment: Is `Drives` injected through Spring? Where does it get the data it needs to create the `FsAccess` instances?

Comment: What do you mean injected through Spring? It gets the data from uPortal. I'm restructuring a portlet for uPortal.

Comment: Not being familiar with uPortal's workings, where does Spring come into play? The portal itself provides the data to `Drives`?

Comment: uPortal gets user information such as username and group information from active directory.The portlet gets that information from uPortal and uses it to create the drives for the user. This is a briefcase/ file sharing portlet so drives created for the user are really just the locations of that person's shared folders.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Drives` bean is instantiating the `FsAccess` beans in it's initialization phase, you may declare the dependency of the `ServersAccessService` bean via [depends-on](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-dependson) to the `Drives` bean. This forces the initialization of the `Drives` bean before the initialization of the `ServersAccessService` bean.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to make your drives class a @Configuration bean, and make the method that returns a List annotated with @Bean. That way the spring container knows about the FsAccess list and it can be available for injection via @Autowired.

EDIT:

Reference: http://blog.springsource.com/2006/11/28/a-java-configuration-option-for-spring/